# How do we perpendicular force to direction of motion changes only direction but velocity constant or changes direction with increasing velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

If force is perpendicular to the direction of motion. I found two situations as in below.

1. Pls see the first situation below.

   [image]

   We have three object A, B , C. In this situation object B is our interest. From point of view of A, initially objects B and C moving with constant velocity $V_x$. But from point of view of C the object B is stationary. We apply perpendicular force for a smallest possible amount of time on B. From point of view of A the object B changes direction. Now We have $V_x$ remain the same (If V_x decreases then it will left behind from C) but it added $V_y$ , So the magnitude of $V$ increases. Because $V = \sqrt{V_x^2 + V_y^2}$. But from point of view of C the object B start to move with constant velocity toward object C. My question is that in this situation perpendicular force increases the speed $V$, it means magnitude of velocity increases also direction change. But perpendicular force supposed to change direction only not magnitude. What happened here.
2. Second situation take smallest possible part of circular motion.

   [image]

   Here force is again perpendicular to the direction of motion but in this situation only direction changes not the magnitude of velocity. It is only possible when $V_x$ decreases and $V_y$ increases in order the keep $V$ constant in magnitude. Means velocity vector rotation keeps magnitude constant but regularly changes $V_x$ and $V_y$.

How it is possible in above two situation perpendicular force behaves two way. One way increases $V$ by adding $V_y$ and $V_x$ remain constant which also make direction change. But second way it only changes direction which is only possible when $V_x$ decreases and $V_y$ increases to keep $V$ constant. Why there are two different scenarios for perpendicular force?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are not applying a perpendicular force in the sense of a force that is always perpendicular to the body's velocity even as its velocity changes. Instead the force is perpendicular to the body's *initial* velocity; the body is initially moving in the x direction, and you apply a force which is in the -y direction throughout the time that it is being applied.

I suspect that you are misled by the sharpness of B's change of direction in your first diagram. In fact a finite force, $F_y$ must act over a length of time, $\Delta t=\frac{v_y}{F_y/m}$, in order to give the body its extra velocity component, $v_y$, thereby changing the body's direction and giving it extra speed. What appears as a sharp bend in B's path is, in fact, an arc of a parabola. This is because in your first case the force always acts in the -y direction.

By contrast, in the second case you have a force whose direction continuously changes, to be perpendicular to the body's changing velocity. This results in circular motion at constant speed, as any elementary dynamics textbook will demonstrate.

Comment: Hello @Philip Wood . In first situation force is applied perpendicular to the direction of motion for a small amount of time. According to newton's 2nd law it produce acceleration in the $-y$ direction $a_y$ for short amount of time , which is responsible for producing constant $V_y$ but $V_x$ remains the same. In second case of circular motion force again perpendicular to the direction of motion applied for a short amount time but it keeps magnitude $V$ constant which is only possible when $V_x$ decreases and $V_y$ increase. Why perpendicular force act differently in these two situations?

Comment: I apologise for repeating myself, but in one case you are using *perpendicular* to mean perpendicular to the original direction of motion (x direction) and in the other case to mean always perpendicular to the (changing) instantaneous direction of motion. The first results in motion in an arc of a parabola, at increasing speed, the second in motion in an arc of a circle at constant speed. In your first diagram you have drawn the parabolic arc as a sharp bend.

Comment: No i didn't make parabola as sharp bend in my first. I will be parabola if i will constantly apply force in the $-y$ direction. But i applied force for the time $dt$ which creates vertical component of velocity $V_y$ without changing $V_x$. This is the reason why from POV of C object B moving with constant velocity toward C not accelerating. The force perpendicular force is applied in situation which creates circular motion. Why?

Comment: "But i applied force for the time  which creates vertical component of velocity " Your $dt$ is misleading. In order to impart a finite velocity component, $v_y$, to the body using a finite force, that force must be applied for a finite time. It may be that the force is very large, so the time is very short, but nonetheless the body will follow a parabolic arc during that time. The arc may be so 'tight' that it looks like a sharp bend on your diagram.

Comment: Yes you can consider a large force for short amount of time $dt$ which creates $V_y$ and parabolic path for very small time after that object B follow straight line toward C with constant velocity. Why situation changes in circular motion case. The same perpendicular force applied to the uniformly moving object it changes only direction by constant $V$ and decrease $V_x$ and increase $V_y$? How force decide what to do. Whether keeps $V_x$ constant and increase $V_y$ which increase $V$ or decrease $V_x$ and increase $V_y$ to keep $V$ constant. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: How nature decide what to do in next instant of time . Let suppose object is moving with $V_x$. At first instant of time $t_1$ force is perpendicular to the direction of motion. What i think at later instant $t_2$ it will be decided by nature what to do by seeing the direction of force. What happened at $t_2$? I think at first instant $t_1$ nature has both possibilities first is change direction only by $V_x$ decreases and $V_y$ increases and second possibility $V_x$ constant $V_y$ increases. What happened in reality?

Comment: "The same perpendicular force applied to the uniformly moving object?" NO ! In the second case the force is always perpendicular to the body's velocity as it changes its direction. This results in circular motion at constant speed, as any elementary dynamics textbook will show. In case 1. in your question the force is perpendicular to the initial velocity (a velocity in the x-direction. The force stays in the -y direction and is no longer perpendicular to the body's velocity as the body's direction of motion changes – a process which takes a finite time (not well denoted by $dt$ !).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147548/discussion-between-123-and-philip-wood).

Comment: My last comment was a reply to your comment starting "Yes you can consider". I offer no response to your comment starting "How nature decide". Best wishes.

Comment: But this is the point of confusion for me how nature decide what to do at later instant of time. What to do with object either rotate it to keep $V$ constant or increase $V_y$ and keeping $V_x$ constant which causes $V$ increase.

Comment: @123 fyi, Philip Wood is completely correct here. Especially regarding the parabolic bend vs the circular bend. You should listen more and argue less

Comment: Hello @Dale . Basically this phenomenon i was previously known. I have already discussed with peers they gave me same answers as we discussed here. This is kind of gross simplification of phenomenon. I want to know what happened at later instant $t_2$. We know the Force is perpendicular to the direction of motion at first instant $t_1$. If i understand what happened at $t_2$ no matter how much small $\Delta{t}$ is, then same phenomenon repeats in every $\Delta{t}$. No one discussed it this way. I believe the real answer lies here.

Comment: @123 if the force changes direction so that it is always perpendicular to the velocity then you get circular motion. If the force does not change direction so that it is only initially perpendicular then you get parabolic motion. Saying that the force occurs over a brief $dt$ doesn’t change that

Comment: @Dale This happens in reality what you explain. It means nature analyze the direction of force at later instant $t_2$ for both possibilities. If nature found at $t_2$ direction of force is along y-axis again then it keeps $V_x$ same and added small amount of $dV_y$. If nature found force direction change and is compatible with perpendicular to new direction, then nature rotate the object without change $V$ but it change $V_x$ and $V_y$ both. Why you are not accepting my idea what is problem with that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @123 oh well. I tried. Good luck with your studies

Comment: @Dale Thanks for your answer. Most of peoples gives answer conventionally as also written in books. But we can ask questions to understand phenomenon in more ways. But few peoples goes beyond the box. If there is any problem with my question you can tell me , i will accept . But no one said it is wrong with remarks , but still don't give answer.

Comment: "If there is any problem with my question you can tell me". I have done so; I've tried to explain how "perpendicular force behaves two different ways" is because you are using the term *perpendicular* in two different ways. I've now made some changes to my answer to try and make it clearer.